# is solving tower of hanoi possible with two pole parameters and recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

i have been looking into solving the tower of hanoi problem using a set of restrictions on the recursion. the main idea is to create a function

```
hanoi(disks,source_pole,destination_pole):
```

I have already gotten an understanding and solved this problem using four parameters where you add an extra auxillary_pole however i do not quite understand how i would approach solving this efficiently without the auxillary_pole as a parameter.

```
hanoi(3,0,2) #the general format for how the inputs will be received
#source_pole and destination_pole inputs will always be 0 and 2
```

The main error is that even if I declared a variable:

```
auxilliary_pole = 1
```

And then proceed to use it in a code using f-strings like

```
print(f"move from peg {source_pole} to {auxilliary_pole}")
```

It will not work out in the longer run of the code such as where n > 3

I am not looking for code to copy, just the logic or general method i should follow as plagiarising isn't something i want to do.

Comment: `auxilliary_pole = 3 - source_pole - destination_pole`.

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks for the reply, however i do not understand how that would help solve my problem. as ultimately having a 1 as a constant would be the result of that declaration in any case. and both source_pole and destination_pole ultimately are 0 or 2.

Comment: If you have solved the problem using a 4-argument solution, you remove the auxiliary_pole argument to the function, and replace it with the line I give above inside your function. `source_pole` and `destination_pole` are not always 0 and 2, since your code presumably uses recursion and these arguments take different values.

Comment: oh that makes much more sense, it is essentially restructuring your code to take one instance where (1,source,destination) as well. thank you!!!!!